# React JSX: VS Code doesn't change color after using template string literals

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

So as I am writing code in my JSX and I had to come to a point where I used a template string literal using the backticks "`". After using the closing backtick, VS code thinks that I have not closed the string and puts all the following code in the same color. For example:
[image]

As we can see on line 42, I have closed the string literal but I am getting a similar color on line 43 and following. Even the `</Link>` is in orange color. I am not getting any compilation errors but this behavior is irritating to me if I have to write additional code.I am not sure what is the reason behind this and I would like to know how to fix this issue. What I have tried:

1. Closing VS Code --> Didn't work
2. Followed old SO posts about setting the language on the status bar to Javascript React --> Didn't work

I would appreciate some guidance in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the underscore, the glitch persists?

Comment: Are you using any extensions that may be out of date? Try updating the extensions if needed and maybe disable/re-enable them.

Comment: so interestingly I found that putting a "?" inside the template string literal is causing a problem. If i remove the "?" everything is fine and I get no formatting problems but I do get errors on the page stating that my user object is null. So my question is, is there a way to tell visual studio settings to avoid the "?" character in the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to an syntax highlighting extension (Template Literals by julienetie). Disable any similar extensions you may have and you are good to go.

A dumb work-around I found is to add an empty template literal (backtick pair) after every instance of a template literal using special characters. Somehow it works as a reset.

I have no idea if this is a good practice, so don't shoot me!